# Unable to migrate project to Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project that was created in Eclipse. I opened that project in Android Studio and got the message

**Migrate Project to Gradle? This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system. More Information about migrating to Gradle Don't show this message again.**

I tried solving this restarting android studtio. But it didn't work.
Here Run, Build, Sync etc all the options are disabled in studio.

Can any one help me in solving this issue?

Comment: See [how to migrate eclipse to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

Comment: what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: theres nothing wrong with your solution. Its absolutely right. I just accepted Shakeeb's answer as he has given some explaination to it. @PushpendraChoudhary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to open project instead of import. Actually you can directly import project by click on open if existing project is built in Studio environment.But same cant be done to eclipse based project .So try again by import project option.

File -> New-> import project

Answer (score 3):

Import the project instead of open like this:

File -> New-> import project

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project in Android Studio with the same package name, when the project is created, then copy the old projects' src, res, manifest and  assets(if you are using), and paste this in the newly created workspace of Android Studio. Open the studio and sync the project. It will work. Give it a shot.